# How to change culture in Windows Service?

Tags: resources, windows-services, sendmail, culture

How to change culture in Windows Service? I have a service that sends e-mails in English and Portuguese using Resources file. But already I tried the solution below but without success.

Even putting "pt-BR" always remains as "en-US".

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to check whether the localization was build and copied to the folder with other binaries. If not, I advise you to make them **public embedded resource**, and in the build script do so in the section `<CreateItem ...> </ CreateItem>` bin-resources are marked as binaries.

For example, not so:

```
<CreateItem Include="$(ServiceBinPath)\*.*">
```

but like so:

```
<CreateItem Include="$(ServiceBinPath)\**\*.*">
```

because other locales build to sub-folder bin\en\, bin\fr\, etc.

The rest - you specify ways enough to change the locale.